# Learning schedule with multiple languages

Tags: learning-methods, multiple-languages, effectiveness

I am wondering **how to schedule learning my languages** to get the best results and to give each of the languages enough time.

Currently I am learning English(C1), German(B2),Turkish(A2) and Spanish(A2).

I think there are possibly two options:

**1. Learn each day a different language like:**

Mo:German
Tu:Turkish
We:Spanish
Th:German
Fri:Turkish
Sa:Spanish
Su:German

**2. or learn bit of each language everyday** (which I feel like can be quite tricky with a busy schedule)

So if anyone could share his tips/tricks how to deal with it, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally found it more practical to spend a week on each language:

- it takes some time to start "thinking a language"
- it gives time to cover whole concepts/grammatical phenomena, or make a full pass over not too complex books (such as those from "Teach yourself" or "Colloquial" series)
- it allows for making more meaningful parallels between languages
- it allows for relaxing and refocusing, if the langauges are not too similar

This works on initial stages, but beyond A1-A2 (that is beyond the level of the above mentioned introductory books) each language invariably requires more time. I started with four (and played with several others), but eventually focused on the two that I really needed (French and German in my case).